# R: Find average of multiple columns, only for the columns where the value > 0

Tags: r, dataframe, data.table

I have four columns with patients' BMI measurements. Some patients have more measurements than others. 
Example:

```
    id <- c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5)
    bmi1 <- c(18, 25, 20, 30, 32)
    bmi2 <- c(18, 0, 0, 31, 34)
    bmi3 <- c(20, 0, 0, 0, 31)
    bmi4 <- c(0, 0, 0, 0, 32)
    bmi <- data.frame(id, bmi1, bmi2, bmi3, bmi4)
```

I want to create a fifth column, `avg` that averages the four bmi columns [2:5] together, but leaves out the zeros. So it would look like this:

```
      id bmi1 bmi2 bmi3 bmi4   avg
       1   18   18   20    0 18.67
       2   25    0    0    0 25.00
       3   20    0    0    0 20.00
       4   30   31    0    0 30.50
       5   32   34   31   32 32.50
```

So to take the average of row 2, it would simply calculate (25/1), but to take the average of row 1, it would calculate (18+18+20)/3. The IDs need to still be intact.

I've worked some with data table and would be happy for either a data frame or a data table solution.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We convert the '0' values to 'NA' in columns 2:5 and then use `rowMeans` with `na.rm=TRUE`.

```
 bmi[2:5][bmi[2:5]==0]<- NA
```

Or as @David Arenburg mentioned

```
 is.na(bmi[-1]) <- bmi[-1] == 0 #changes 0 values to NA
 bmi$avg <- round(rowMeans(bmi[2:5], na.rm=TRUE),2)
 bmi$avg
 #[1] 18.67 25.00 20.00 30.50 32.25
```

---

The above solution changes the '0' values to 'NA' in the original dataset, but if we don't want to change the values in the original 'bmi' object, then use `replace` with `rowMeans`.

```
 rowMeans(replace(bmi[2:5], bmi[2:5]==0, NA), na.rm=TRUE)
```

Comment: +1 It's worth noting that this changes OPs data set. However, I think that setting `0` to `NA` really is the best (and safest) way to go here.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a base-r solution with apply:

```
bmi$avg=apply(bmi[,2:4],1,function(x) mean(x[x !=0 ]))
```

Comment: This worked for my example but with my data I am getting the following error message: `Error in apply(bmi[, 26:28], 1, function(x) mean(x[x !=  : 
  dim(X) must have a positive length`

Comment: @epi_n00b I don't know what's happening here without seeing the data

Answer (score 2):

Here's another possibility

```
round(rowSums(bmi[-1]) / rowSums(bmi[-1] != 0), 2)
# [1] 18.67 25.00 20.00 30.50 32.25
```

This is just divides the row sums by the number of non zero values per row.

---

Or (if you don't have `NA`s) if we want to avoid matrix conversion

```
round(Reduce(`+`, bmi[-1]) / rowSums(bmi[-1] != 0), 2)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 `%notin%` <- function(x,y) !(x %in% y)
  bmi$avg <- apply(bmi[2:4],1, function(x) sum(x) / length(which(bmi[x,1] %notin% 0)))
```

This might also work.